# Sending a String and Int to Function via Text File

Tags: c++, function, text-files, ifstream

I am trying to read in a text file that has a name and age on each line such as this

```
Tom
55
Bob
12
Tim
66
```

I then need to pass it to a function which takes in a string and an int such as:

```
sortDLL.Insert(name, age);
```

However, I am unsure how to do this.  I tested it out with the following and it works (bypassing the text file):

```
string tom = "tom";
string bob = "bob";
string tim = "tim";
int a = 55;
int b = 12;
int c = 66;

     sortDLL.Insert(tom, a);
     sortDLL.Insert(bob, b);
     sortDLL.Insert(tim, c);
```

But when I try to read in the text file and send it, the program doesn't run properly.  This is what I am currently trying, and I have messed around with a few other things, but have had no luck:

```
ifstream infile ("names.txt");


while(getline(infile, line));
{
    istringstream ss(line);
    if (ss >> name)
        cin >> name;
    else if (ss >> wt)
        cin >> wt;

    sortDLL.Insert(name, wt);


}
infile.close();
```

Like always, any help to get this to work would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should not have ; (semi-colon) at the end of while statement `while(getline(infile, line));`

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out, dunno how that slipped by.  Unfortunately, that is not the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct code should look like this. Remember you have to read 2 line per 1 insert.

```
while(getline(infile, line))
{
    stringstream ss(line);

    ss >> wt;
    if(ss.fail()) {
        name = line;
        continue;
    }
    else {
        // cout << name << ":" << wt << endl;
        sortDLL.Insert(name, wt);
    }
}
```

Comment: The cout prints to the screen properly, with both name and age, however it still isn't doing anything when passing it through to the function (the console just stays empty).  Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: Ahhhhh...so upset with myself haha.  That worked perfectly, I accidentally commented out my print statement, while I was commenting out some other code in my main.  Thanks so much for the help!